# eBay API multiple variations for images

Tags: xml, ebay-api

I can't reason the Trading API for variation Images. The XML they propose is

```
<Pictures> PicturesType
    <VariationSpecificName> string </VariationSpecificName>
    <VariationSpecificPictureSet> VariationSpecificPictureSetType
      <PictureURL> anyURI </PictureURL>
      <!-- ... more PictureURL values allowed here ... -->
      <VariationSpecificValue> string </VariationSpecificValue>
    </VariationSpecificPictureSet>
    <!-- ... more VariationSpecificPictureSet nodes allowed here ... -->
</Pictures>
```

And you can have multiple `Picture` blocks.

So that Might look like

```
<item>
<variations>
    <Pictures>
        <VariationSpecificName>Color</variationSpecificName>
        <VariationSpecificPictureSet>
            <VariationSpecificValue> Blue </VariationSpecificValue>
            <PictureURL> ... </<PictureURL>
            <PictureURL> ... </<PictureURL>
        </VariationSpecificPictureSet>
        <VariationSpecificPictureSet>
            <VariationSpecificValue> Red </VariationSpecificValue>
            <PictureURL> ... </<PictureURL>
            <PictureURL> ... </<PictureURL>
        </VariationSpecificPictureSet>
    </Pictures>
    <Pictures>
        <VariationSpecificName>Size</variationSpecificName>
        <VariationSpecificPictureSet>
            <VariationSpecificValue> M </VariationSpecificValue>
            <PictureURL> ... </<PictureURL>
            <PictureURL> ... </<PictureURL>
        </VariationSpecificPictureSet>
    </Pictures>
</variations>
</item>
```

But as you can see, this is 2 picture blocks, 1 for color and 1 for size. And inside color there are values. Blue and Red.  But images are for BLUE and MEDIUM.  Not just Blue and not just Medium.

I don't see any way with this structure to specify an image for BLUExMEDIUM and BLUExLARGE and REDxMEDIUM etc..

Answer (score 1):

Turns out can only have an image set for one variation type. You can't do blue x large. Just blue or large.

Comment: That's still the case? 2022?